# Is 5 * 5 a literal or just an expression?

Tags: java, constants, literals

I know that for example `'5'` is literal of type `char` but is `5 * 5` a literal? This is expression, however it has fixed value.

Comment: You may wish to indicate which language you're using.

Comment: And probably which parser/compiler you're using. An intelligent one should automatically transform `5 * 5` to `25` if working with math operations.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I guess its kind of obvious its Java considering the #java tag.

Comment: @Craig at the time the comment was posted, it only had the "literals" tag.

Answer (score 12):

As described in [Java Language Specification §15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28), it's a particular case of expression called "compile-time constant expression". It's not a literal.

Comment: There is no way to tell from the byte code whether this was written as `5 * 5` or `25` +1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can call it a literal.  It's possible that some compilers will treat it the same way they deal with a literal, see the comment about which language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

"Literal" is a grammatical term, not semantical. It is the basic building block that denotes a constant value.

Although by specification `5 * 5` and `25` mean exactly the same, grammatically the first one is a binary expression involving two literals and an operator, and the second one is just a literal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but doesnt that terms work something like that?

- while you use some value to define exactly value of variable "in
  straight way" it should be called as "literal"

  > `var num =5; var stringLabel = "someText";` etc.
- while you use some formula or prescription it should be called as "expression"

  > `var result = 5*5; var res2 = a*x;`

But of course- in **result** that also constant si it also can be literal in fact ..

That's how get it at least me..

It's just about terms- also like in java there are methods, "C languages" are functions, etc. - in meanings its also the same things, so it depends just on the limit what will you tolerate at all :D